# Can't use function in data frame which is converted from Html File

Tags: python, pandas

I have one html file where table is stored and I store that html file into pandas Dataframe like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
table = BeautifulSoup(open('/home/lenovo/Downloads/F4311.html','r').read()).find('table')

# You are passing a <class 'bs4.element.Tag'> element into pandas read_html. You need to convert it to a string.
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
```

It worked and i could print df too. Then I tried to list it's column name.

```
cols_df=df.columns.tolist()
```

It threw an error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Then I tried to export to csv file.

```
df.to_csv("data.csv")
```

It threw me an error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

Please help me in fixing these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the documentation for [`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html), you will find that it returns not a *dataframe*, but "[a] *list* of DataFrames". This explains the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

I.e. your actual `pd.DataFrame` will be the first item in a list that you have called `df`. I.e. you access it by using `df[0]`.